# why output file is larger than original?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I read a file from resource folder and trying to write in another file

```
 InputStream is = new ClassPathResource(fileName).getInputStream();
 OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName+"test");
 byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
 int length;
 while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
     outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
 }
 outputStream.close();
 is.close();
```

But output file didn't open.
I noticed that:
Size of original ~ 500kb.
Size of output file 1Mb

and i don't understand root cause of problem in size of file

I tested on pdf file.
Update.
I write test and this code work, but don't work in SpringBoot application

Comment: is the output file the same as the input ? in the code you're using the same filename.

Comment: @benbenw no, they are different

Comment: Where is ClassPathResource defined? Perhaps it is uncompressing a stream for you, so you are writing the uncompressed image.

Comment: @DuncG ClassPathResource from org.springframework.core.io. How to compressing a stream? maybe there is another way to read pdf file from the resource folder?

Comment: You might want to tag the question for spring framework. Normally I'd read classpath resources using `Class.getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)` but don't use Spring so can't help you.

Comment: @DuncG I added tag

Answer (score 0):

```
<resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.yml</include>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
                <include>**/*.txt</include>
                <include>**/*.json</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.pdf</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```